# Trying to copy worksheets in multiple pdfs - Syntax Error

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing, type-conversion

Could you kindly help me with this code? I am a beginner..

```
Sub ExportSheetstoPDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mywsname As String

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    mywsname = ws.Name
    Activesheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:="Z:\Incent_2022\ORDINARIA\RETAIL-WHS\Schede Obiettivi\Q1\" & "Schede Obiettivi Retail Classico Q1 22_" & mywsname & “.pdf”, _

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the line

```
Activesheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:="Z:\Incent_2022\ORDINARIA\RETAIL-WHS\Schede Obiettivi\Q1\" & "Schede Obiettivi Retail Classico Q1 22_" & mywsname & “.pdf”, _
```

has the continuation character _ at the end of it, but nothing continues on the next line.

Remove the `,_` from the end of the line

Also the `“.pdf”` needs to be `".pdf"` i.e. using ordinary double-quotes and not ones copied out of an Office document ("intelligent" double-quotes)